# How to add external GPIO interrupts on STM32?

Tags: interrupts, gpio, stm32f103c8t6

I'm trying to configure STM32CubeMx to external GPIO interrupts, however, in the NVIC screen I don't see an EXTI... interrupt to be set.

What should I do to be able to e.g. check for interrupts on GPIO pin PB14, PB13 and PB12?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the pin you want to configure, then select GPIO_EXT# in the dropdown menu, that should enable the EXTI line in the NVIC menu. [image]
[image]

On the other Hand, CubeMX isnt perfect and it might not have the interrupt on the pins you want well implemented

Comment: Thanks ... I configured the pins as GPIO_Input, overlooked GPIO_EXTI..